# Specific assembly commands functions

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I'm new to learning assembly language, and I'm wondering what this commands mean, they are not in any specific order

```
mov al,[si]
mov [di],al 
inc si
inc di
dec cx
jnz b20
jnz b21
movah 09h`
```

Thanks in advance for your answer.
The code that was provided to me:

```
Page 60,132
. Model small
. Stack 64
.data nom db 'FAUSTINO','$'
ape db 'VAZQUEZ','$'
nomcom db 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO','$'
.code
begin proc far
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax
mov cx,08
lea si,nom
lea di,
nomcom
b20:
mov al,[si]
mov [di],al
inc si
inc di
dec cx
jnz b20
mov cx,07
lea si,ape
b21:
mov al,[si]
mov [di],al
Inc si
Inc di
Dec cx
Jnz b21
mov ah, 09h ;
Lea dx, nomcom ;
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
begin endp
end begin
```

Comment: They are in a specific order.  Copy then increment pointers.  And dec/jnz so JNZ reads flags set by `dec`.  You could increment the pointers in the other order, or increment the source pointer after loading, before storing, but most other orders for the loop body would break it.

Comment: If you want to know what each one does individually, look them up in an instruction-set reference.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/index.html

Answer (score 0):

### The little details

`mov al,[si]` reads one byte from memory using the address stored in the `SI` register.

`mov [di],al` writes one byte to memory using the address stored in the `DI` register.

`inc si` raises the source address by 1.

`inc di` raises the destination address by 1.

`dec cx` lowers the loop counter by 1.

`jnz b20` continues the loop for as long as the loop counter hasn't fallen to zero.

### The big picture

> ```
> .data
> nom db 'FAUSTINO','$'
> ape db 'VAZQUEZ','$'
> nomcom db 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO','$'
> ```

Given the above data definitions and the setup of the registers `SI`, `DI`, and `CX`, the program first **copies** the 8-characters text "FAUSTINO" over the text "ABCDEFGH" and then **copies** the 7-characters text "VAZQUEZ" over the text "IJKLMNO". Because everything snuggly fits, the destination buffer at *nomcom* now holds "FAUSTINOVAZQUEZ$". This has the correct format to submit to the DOS.PrintString function 09h. Sadly your program misses the necessary `int 21h` instruction and so the program terminates before having output the joined result.

```
    mov cx, 8       ; Length of the text "FAUSTINO"
    lea si, nom     ; Address of the text "FAUSTINO"
    lea di, nomcom  ; Address of destination buffer
b20:
    mov al, [si]
    mov [di], al
    inc si
    inc di
    dec cx
    jnz b20

    mov cx, 7       ; Length of the text "VAZQUEZ"
    lea si, ape     ; Address of the text "VAZQUEZ"
b21:
    mov al, [si]
    mov [di], al
    inc si
    inc di
    dec cx
    jnz b21

    mov ah, 09h     ; DOS.PrintString
    lea dx, nomcom
    int 21h
    mov ax, 4C00h   ; DOS.Terminate
    int 21h
```

The initial content in the buffer at *nomcom* is of no importance except for the 16th byte which holds the DOS string terminator "$".
The data definition for *nomcom* could have been written as:

```
nomcom db 15 dup (0), '$'
```

The program would have performed just the same. However using the `dup` operator is the more usual form to define a buffer!